# Is ⊢ countable or uncountable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

In Propositional Logic and First Order Logic, is ⊢ countable or uncountable?

Also, please describe why it is countable or uncountable infinity.

To clarify, consider the following statement:

`Γ ⊢ φ`

Here, `⊢` is a relation. Now how big this relation can get considering all kind of possibilities?

Comment: With $\vdash$ do you mean the [derivability relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)#Interpretations) ?

Comment: Yes. The turnstyle.

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you're asking, but: certainly "$\Gamma\vdash\varphi$" makes sense even if $\Gamma$ is uncountable, and $\Gamma$ can be arbitrarily large depending on the size of your language. (So in fact, when considering all possible formulas in all possible languages, $\vdash$ is really a *proper class*.) If this isn't what you mean, you need to make your question more precise (and even if it is what you mean you need to clarify that).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You're much more likely to get a response if you can tell us what you've thought about the problem, what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have clarified the question a bit.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Usually, size of relation between two sets of size m and n is 2^(m*n). So, As it is exponential and n can be aleph-null, it seems like it should be uncountable. But I'm not sure

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh Your previous comment is incorrect; a relation is a set of ordered pairs, so a relation between $A$ and $B$ has size at most $\vert A\times B\vert$. $2^{\vert A\times B\vert}$ is the size of *the set of all relations* between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation "$\vdash$" can be arbitrarily large.

First of all, the number of formulas in a given language *depends on the size of that language*. In a language of size $\aleph_{17}$, there are $\aleph_{17}$-many formulas.

This tells us two things:

- The cardinality of $\Gamma$ in an expression of the form "$\Gamma\vdash\varphi$"can be arbitrarily large.
- The relation $\vdash$, therefore, is a proper class: it is too big to even have a cardinality.

Now *if we fix a given (size of a) language*, things change. E.g. if our language is countable, then there are only countably many formulas, hence continuum-many sets of formulas, and $\vdash$ - viewed as a set of ordered pairs - has cardinality continuum. But this depends on the choice of (size of) language.

Comment: Will you stop with the "17 is the random integer"? :D

Comment: @AsafKaragila NEVER.

Comment: I will ask you this 16 more times. Then by your own construction, you'd consider me to have asked you this an arbitrary number of times, which would then cause infinitely many false memories of me asking this $n$ times, therefore bringing you to the brink of madness as your brain collapses into an infinitely strong black hole that will devour the universe and devoid it of meaning, and in particular this issue with 17 will be gone.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I thought Ramanujan showed that $17$ is the smallest natural number with no interesting properties.

Comment: @David: But is it the least arbitrary natural number?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Depends on how you parse "the least arbitrary natural number".

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\vdash   \subseteq \mathcal{P}(Fm) \times Fm$. Taking $\phi$ as theorem, we have $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ for all $\Gamma \subset Fm$. Therefore...

Comment: What is Fm? The (Alphabet set)*?

Comment: The formula algebras, the formulas that you construct from the alphabet set.

Comment: Actually, I am new to this. So I need a little more clarification. As per my understanding, the formulas constructed from alphabet set is countably infinite. Now as ⊢⊆P(Fm)×Fm, the size of the relation ⊢ will be exponential, which means it is uncountably infinite - Is this correct?

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh The set of formulas depends on the alphabet - if the alphabet is uncountable, so will be the set of formulas. This is what my comment above was getting at.